WebSocket connection to 'wss://myconnection.cloudapp.azure.com/nodeserver/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed
Websocket connection fail for subsequent request. Initially connected and receive below response.

and very next subsequent requests like this

here is my socket code
using this package import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
this.socket = io(socketUrl,
    {
        transports: ["websocket"],
        path: "/"+ingress+"/socket.io/",
        auth: {
          userId: userId,
          token: token
        }
      });
 this.socket.on('connect_err', err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
 this.socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
      console.warn("Disconnected:", reason);
    }
  });

immediately disconnected connection showing error transport close

